# Infinite loop with function call in post

Tags: go

Cycle loops, when I increment `i` by the function, but no via `i++`.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func increment(i int) (int) {
    i++
    return i
}

func condition_true(i int) (bool) {
    if i < 10 {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

func main() {
    for i := 1; condition_true(i); increment(i) {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

[compiler to play around](https://repl.it/Js55/1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do `i = increment(i)`.

Otherwise, the `i` used in the loop is not modified.

```
for i := 1; condition_true(i); i = increment(i) {
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

That one works as you'd expect.

https://play.golang.org/p/dwHbV1iY0_

Alternatively, allow `increment` to modify `i` by receiving a pointer to it:

```
func increment(i *int) {
   *i++
}
```

And then use it like this in the loop:

```
for i := 1; condition_true(i); increment(&i) {
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because the increment function isn't actually changing the i value because the i is passed by value into the function.

Simply remove the increment in the for loop and replace it with i++